# preg_replace() Заменить только первую подмаску

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть рег. выражение:

```
(\s*\S+\s\S+,\s*)([^<]*<\/td>\s+<\/tr>)
```

И есть массив строк таблицы, который лежит в переменной $trs3.

Мне нужно с помощью рег выражения заменить на пробел в каждой строке таблицы только то, что что соответствует: `(\s*\S+\s\S+,\s*)`

Насколько я понимаю, мне нужно получить **matches[1]?**
Я пытаюсь использовать **preg_replace()**, т.к. эта функция позволяет искать по массиву. Но я нигде не нашла упоминаний, что в ней можно применять matches[1].

А **preg_match_all**, насколько я понимаю, только со строкой работает. 
Применить ее к каждой строке массива, лежащего в $trs3, мне решительно не хватает ума, ибо я новичок в пхп.

Подскажите, как можно решить мою задачу?

Comment: `preg_replace('~\s*\S+\s\S+,\s*([^<]*</td>\s+</tr>)~', ' $1', $massiv_strok)`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!

Answer (score 0):

Используйте

```
$massiv_strok = preg_replace('~\s*\S+\s\S+,\s*([^<]*</td>\s+</tr>)~', ' $1', $massiv_strok);
```

Смысл в том, что захватываемая подмаска нужна только для того текста, который требуется оставить как есть. В данном случае первая подмаска лишняя, её необходимо удалить, а шаблон замены нужно исправить на `' $1'`, где `$1` — обратная ссылка на значение первой захватывающей подмаски.